# Компоновка виджетов Qt Designer

Tags: qt, gui, qt-designer, qlayout

Возникла такая ситуация, для моей программы нужен кастомный тайтлбар. Его я и сделал -

1. Добавил `QFrame` и поменял его цвет
2. В этот `QFrame` добавил кнопку, которая будет выполнять нужный функционал

Теперь вопрос. Мне нужно так скомпоновать этот `TitleBar`, чтобы расстягивался только он. Если скомпоновать '`centralwidget`' по сетке (`gridLayout`), выходит что `TitleBar` скомпонован, все хорошо, но добавлю еще один виджет (к примеру кнопку) и `TitleBar` сразу же стал в 5 раз меньше, а кнопка растянулась на весь экран.

Значит пробовал я сделать путем добавления `TitleBar` в виджет и скомпоновать этот виджет, но оно не расстягивается

[image: Схема]

Если нужен **`.ui`** файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>652</width>
    <height>412</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">#centralWidget {
border-image: url(:/img/wallpaper.jpg);
}
#applemenu {
border-image: url(:/img/mbar_logo.png);
}
#applemenu:pressed {
border-image: url(:/img/clickedbut.jpg);
}
#menu {
background-color: rgb(233, 187, 223);
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>651</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <property name="leftMargin">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <item>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="menubar">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>16777215</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(233, 187, 223)</string>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="applemenu">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>18</width>
          <height>18</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>18</width>
          <height>18</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>18</width>
          <height>18</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui`, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял то, что вы хотите сделать, но предложу попробовать так:

**q1431163.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>564</width>
    <height>417</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>5</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);</string>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShape">
           <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShadow">
           <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
          </property>
          <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="horizontalSpacing">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item row="0" column="0">
            <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2" stretch="0">
             <property name="spacing">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="leftMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="topMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="bottomMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(170, 0, 127);
font: 75 12pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color: rgb(255, 255, 0);</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Tiitle</string>
               </property>
               <property name="alignment">
                <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>A</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>B</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>C</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 170, 0);</string>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну типа того, я просто хотел посмотреть как правильно размещать объекты. В каких layout типа

Comment: @Nedaxses то что я вам предложил, это просто один из возможных вариантов и не более.